# Can I replace a call to await Task.Delay with an async method that has inside a await Task.Delay?

Tags: c#

I have this code that is inside an `async` method:

```
// some actions
if (App.pauseCard == true)
{
    vm.Msg1 = "ABC";
    await Task.Delay(500, cts.Token);
    return;
}
// some actions
```

Can someone tell me if it's okay to replace with this:

```
// some actions
if (App.pauseCard == true)
{
    SetMessageViewAsync();
    return;
}
// some actions
```

And this `async` method:

```
private async void SetMessageViewAsync()
{
   vm.Msg1 = "ABC";
   await Task.Delay(500, cts.Token);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. Try increasing the delay to something like 5000 - you will clearly see the second code does not wait anymore.

This is because `async void` method is "fire-and-forget" - meaning once the execution reaches the first actual `await` it just returns and the thread continues executing while the task is underway on another thread - in this case the `return` is executed before the delay is up.

If you change the method's signature to `async Task` and `await` it, the code will be equivalent:

```
private async Task SetMessageViewAsync()
{
   vm.Msg1 = "ABC";
   await Task.Delay(500, cts.Token);
}

// some actions
if (App.pauseCard == true)
{
    await SetMessageViewAsync();
    return;
}
// some actions
```